# Wordpress Ajax success always returns 0

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I tried several solutions that I found in google like adding `die()` at the end of the function etc. but none of them worked.

Here's my ajax script file

```
                            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                                var ajaxurl = '{$siteurl}';
                                jQuery.ajax({
                                    type: 'POST', 
                                    url: ajaxurl, 
                                    data: {'action': 'add_to_cart', 'file_id':23},
                                    success: function(data){ 
                                        console.log('success'+data);
                                    },
                                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                                        console.log('error');
                                    }
                                });
                            });
```

And here's my function

```
add_action('wp_ajax_add_to_cart', 'add_to_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_to_cart', 'add_to_cart');

function add_to_cart(){
    $name = $_POST['file_id'];
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert(
        'rtl21016_custom_cart',
        array(
            'user_id' => 1
        )
    );
    die();
    return true;
}
```

I know this is a common question but I still don't understand why my code still returns zero in success response.
Thanks in advance

Comment: add `die()` end of the your `add_to_cart` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX will return anything that is printed on the page, so returning won't do it for you. Try this:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_add_to_cart', 'add_to_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_to_cart', 'add_to_cart');

function add_to_cart(){
    $name = $_POST['file_id'];
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert(
        'rtl21016_custom_cart',
        array(
            'user_id' => 1
        )
    );
    echo true;
    die();
}
```

Comment: What output is given if you send the POST data through postman or a form?

Comment: It is fixed now . I am editing the wrong theme file function in wordpress. :( Thank you !

Comment: Always the simple mistakes! Please mark an answer as correct :)!

Answer (score 1):

In your "add_to_cart" function your are using die() function before return function that why its returning false in response use the below script as given below:

```
function add_to_cart(){
    $name = $_POST['file_id'];
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert(
        'rtl21016_custom_cart',
        array(
            'user_id' => 1
        )
    );

    echo true;
  die();
}
```

Comment: do one thing comment the whole code inside the add to cart function then add this line echo "i am here"; die(); then then check the ajax response

Comment: i think your ajax request is not going into add to cart function that why you are not getting any response in ajax..please check your script

Comment: It is fixed now . I am editing the wrong theme file function in wordpress. :( Thank you !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103714/discussion-between-rahul-sharma-and-katherine).